# FlipView - remove tilt when swiping

Tags: java, android

I have FlipView with three layouts with full screen images.

I set animation, all working fine, but when i swipe to right I get TILT effect on the right side(like image goes left for 20-30px(I see white background) and get back to normal on center screen).

Don't know where I gave him that properties...

My animations looks like this:

flipin.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="500"
        />
</set>
```

flipinreverse.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="500"
        />
</set>
```

flipout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="-100%p"
        android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

flipoutreverse.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="100%p"
        android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

And Activity code for detecting moves:

```
ViewFlipper page;

Animation animFlipInForeward;
Animation animFlipOutForeward;
Animation animFlipInBackward;
Animation animFlipOutBackward;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tips_screen);

    page = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewflipper);

    animFlipInForeward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flipin);
    animFlipOutForeward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flipout);
    animFlipInBackward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flipin_reverse);
    animFlipOutBackward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flipout_reverse);

}

private void SwipeRight(){
    page.setInAnimation(animFlipInBackward);
    page.setOutAnimation(animFlipOutBackward);
    page.showPrevious();
}

private void SwipeLeft(){
    page.setInAnimation(animFlipInForeward);
    page.setOutAnimation(animFlipOutForeward);
    page.showNext();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener simpleOnGestureListener
        = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                           float velocityY) {

        float sensitvity = 100;
        if((e1.getX() - e2.getX()) > sensitvity){
            SwipeLeft();
        }else if((e2.getX() - e1.getX()) > sensitvity){
            SwipeRight();
        }

        return true;
    }

};

GestureDetector gestureDetector
        = new GestureDetector(simpleOnGestureListener);
```

And one more question:

-My background pictures are too big(1080x1920.....), located in drawables for all screen sizes. They take up to 2-3megabytes each, can I reduce somehow that size?

Comment: I solved this by removing line:
- android:interpolator="@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator">  And adding ShareInterpolator = "false", tilt was removed.   Can someone help me with Image size and then lock and solve this question. I hope that it will help someone too. :)